# Which characters are confirmed to be faster than Flashy Flash?

Tags: one-punch-man

In one of the last chapters of the manga, Flashy Flash mentioned 4 characters who are faster than him

> Saitama - Blast - Garou - Platinum Sperm

Are these characters the only ones to be confirmed to be faster than him?

Which characters are confirmed to be faster than Flashy Flash?